# How to Use v-date-picker with range props from vuetify

Tags: javascript, date, vue.js, vuetify.js

I already read documentation several time about v-date-picker and I think what I want to use is one of these feature, `v-date-picker` with `range` props. But I don't know why I can't seem to implement it in my project. there is several error that I found such as:

1. `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: dateString.split is not a function"` I read some answer in here: [using-new-date-with-v-date-picker-doesnt-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427705/using-new-date-with-v-date-picker-doesnt-work?rq=1) but it still not solve my problem
2. `Error in render: "TypeError: dateString.trim is not a function"`

this is my current progress:

[image: you can see It show the field but I can't click the datepicker anywhere]

for information I'm using `vuetify: "^1.5.16"` for my project. this is the example of my code:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <v-date-picker v-model="dates" range></v-date-picker>
  <v-text-field v-model="dateRangeText" label="Date range" prepend-icon="event" readonly></v-text-field>
  model: {{ dates }}
 <div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      dates: ['2019-09-10', '2019-09-20']
    };
  },

  computed: {
    token() {
        return this.$store.state.auth.token;
    },
    dateRangeText () {
      return this.dates.join(' ~ ')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

in fact I just follow the step in [Here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#date-pickers-range) can someone help me to solve this? I'm confused about this `v-date-picker` with `range` props problem.

Just for reference, I already tried this but it still failed:

1. [how-to-display-a-fixed-vuetify-v-date-picker-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58701481/how-to-display-a-fixed-vuetify-v-date-picker-range)

I follow this answer but this is what I got:

[image: Result after I try the answer above]

I change my dates to: `dates: [new Date('2019-09-10').toJSON(), new Date('2019-09-20').toJSON()],` and the error is still there. can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: hey @Rakish, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Have you fixed this? If not, can you provide working example, not only the code?